# Code Igniter- forms

Tags: codeigniter

I have a view. In this view

```
<form id="validate'>
some fields are here.
</form>
<form>
</form>
<input type="Submit" value ="Submit" >
```

Now submit button will not work since it is in below and I want form id="validate" to get posted.

Since I have to do some JS validation on form id="validate" this will also not work.

My question here is how to post the form and validate the form. Let em know, I f I am not clear here.

Comment: instead of submit why dont you try button and add event handler then (although I am not sure with the code you provided..what exactly you are looking for) and why your submit button is outside the form ??

Comment: Does Submit button here works?

Comment: Why is your `submit` button _outside_ of your `<form></form>` in the first place?  Can you provide more information about what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy with JQuery if you are using it

```
<form id="validate'>
    some fields are here.
</form>

var validation  =   $('#validate').validate();
```

if validation is successfull

```
$('#validate').submit();
```

else

```
//do something else
```

Comment: With out submit button, how will a user submit ? Can you be a bit clear.

Comment: call an event on any button or text box or else and the event will submit the form after successfull validation

Comment: First, there is no such thing as `.validate()` built into jQuery.  It's a third party plugin.  Secondly, your code is not quite correct or complete.  If validation is successful, the plugin automatically does the `submit()`, so there's no need for a conditional test at all.  I'd suggest that the OP [more thoroughly researches the _proper_ ways to use the jQuery Validate plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) if he decides to go that route.

Comment: that's what i mean to say that use either a plugin or define conditions for validation